# Get URL of WCF call

Tags: web-services, wcf

I need to find out the subdomain from which a SOAP-based client calls a WCF-method. While that is quite easy if your're on ASP.NET by using HttpContext.Current, I could not find an equivalent for WCF.

The reason why I need this value is, because I want to host a multi-tenant application which consists of a Web-Frontend (like "foo.myservice.com") and also provides a SOAP-based API (like "foo.myservice.com/Services/ClientService.svc").

Any idea? 
Thany you!

Comment: There is no equivalent - if you need such an information, I would recommend sending it separately, as a header in your SOAP message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you are using HTTP based binding, you can either enable the ASP.NET compatibility to access `HttpContext` or use `OperationContext` to gather the data you want.

`OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To` should work in your case and return the  Uri of the request.

Comment: @John I think he wants to get the subdomain name of the request to use for his multi-tenant application. It is a common requirement in the multitenancy world. Please read carefully!

Comment: I _did_ read it, and I think he wants to know the "subdomain from which a SOAP-based client calls a WCF-method". _from_ which, not _to_ which.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right - my intend was to build a multi-tenant application, and therefore I need to take care of the subdomain. In the meantime I solved the problem by adding a string-parameter to every service-method containing the tenant-name. This is of course an ugly solution and I will go and adapt your suggestion! Thank you.

@John: Sorry for not being clear, what my requirement excatly was.